# Active directory 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have 3 domain controlers
2x 2008
1x 2003 server

When i use the nltest /server:dcN.domain.local /sc_verify:domain.local 
i get: on the 2 of them OK status
on one of them i get
I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

i did some tests and when i moved the role "Domain Role Owner" from the server i had the error to another DC the error moved also

is there any connection with the Domain role owner role? and the 1355 error?
////

To be more clear about:

1. dc1 server
   FMSO role "domain owner role"
   testing nltest /sc_verify:domain.local
   error:  I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN
2. dc2 server
   no FMSO role
   testing nltest /sc_verify:domain.local
   success

now i move fmso domain owner rule to server DC2

1. dc1 server
   FMSO none
   testing nltest /sc_verify:domain.local
   sucess
2. dc2 server
   FMSO role "domain owner role"
   testing nltest /sc_verify:domain.local
   error:  I_NetLogonControl failed: Status = 1355 0x54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN

Comment: OK if someone will have the same Q i will reply to myself

"nltest /sc_verify:domain.com" is not a reliable test to check the current secure channel status because it reports the last known state. 

If the SC is broken you'll get replication errors and access denied in ie. dcdiag logs.

If replication is good, then the SC is good. Verify with ie. "repadmin /replsum"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"nltest /sc_verify:domain.com" is not a reliable test to check the current secure channel status because it reports the last known state.

If the SC is broken you'll get replication errors and access denied in ie. dcdiag logs.

If replication is good, then the SC is good. Verify with ie. "repadmin /replsum"

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that the error moved with the Domain Role Owner. I checked with a domain with a 2008 and a 2003 DC and got the error on the one not holding the role and the error stayed there after transferring the role to this server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal error. I have deployed a test domain with two Domain Controllers, because I had exactly the same error on my production environment. Additionally, the following would also generate an error normally:

```
netdom verify DC2 /domain:test.local

The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
The command failed to complete successfully.
```

After I open a support ticket with Microsoft, and they told me that it is normal. I deployed a test environment forest similar to my production forest, and the results are the same.

Don't worry about this result. This will also occur in Windows Server 2012 R2. And will always occur on Domain Controller with PDC role.